# Error while importing tensorflow.keras in VScode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-import, importerror

Trying to import tensorflow.keras in VScode, however no matter what happened or I tried I would not import nor would it detect the library.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIR9D.png)
I receive the error that vscode cannot detect my tensorflow. I had suspected that the installation was incorrect or did not install correctly so I had uninstalled and reinstalled using both pip and conda. Still vscode cannot find the library.... I also tried using different methods to retrieve these libraries, but they were all in vain.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to select the correct python interpreter.
Press ctrl+shift+p then search for python interpreter.
Click on it then select the correct interpreter that belongs to the conda.

You can find more information here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to import the `tensorflow.keras` module. In fact you just need to import `tensorflow` but put `tf.keras` in front of each module. Like so:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dropout
tf.keras.layers.LSTM
```